# Derived push-forward of projective sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, derived-functors

Let S,X be schemes and $s \in S$ be a closed point. Let $D(X)$ be the derived category of complexes of sheaves.

Let
$$i_s: X \cong  {s} \times X \hookrightarrow S \times X$$ be the natural embedding.

Is the sheaf push-forward $i_{S*} \mathcal{O}_X$ the same as derived push-forward $\mathbf{R}i_{s*} \mathcal{O}_X$?

More generally, let $f: Y \to X$ be a scheme morphism, and $E \in D(Y)$. Suppose $F$ is a complex of projective sheaves, and $F \cong E $ in $D(Y)$ (say a locally free resolution of $E$). Then is $f_* F \cong \mathbf{R}f_* E$ in $D(E)$?

Comment: What kind of sheaves do you mean? (Quasi)-coherent sheaves? General $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules?

Comment: About "more generally": think about when $X$ is a point and $F$ is $O_Y$. Do you think your isomorphism holds in that case?

Comment: @Sebastian I don't know what is the correct setting, but let's assume $D(X)$ to be the bounded complex of coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules for simplicity.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Then what is $E$ in your case?

Comment: @LiYutong: sorry, I meant both $F$ and $E$ should be $O_Y$.

Comment: I see what you mean. So in this case, the derived pushforward may not even be a sheaf.

Comment: @LiYutong: Yes. For a simple example, if $Y$ is an elliptic curve, then $R^1f_*O_Y = H^1(Y,O_Y)$ is nonzero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is a closed immersion, or more generally relatively affine morphism of schemes, then $f_*$ is exact on quasi-coherent sheaves. In other words higher pushforwards $R^i f_*(F) = 0$ are all zero if $i>0$. So the answer for the first question is yes. For the second one the answer is no, if $f$ is not affine; see comments for a counter-example. I assume that $D(X)$ means derived category of quasi-coherent sheaves.